# Do 3 in 1 plantings cause girdling?

Tags: trees, shrubs

I was watching some videos on how to plant trees close together, and was wondering if doing a 3 in 1 planting will cause girdling, or any other problems.

Comment: Hi! What does 3 in 1 plantings mean? I'm just confused because I've never heard the term. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not girdling, but they can't be left to their own devices and be expected to thrive. It's possible one or two could be overpowered by the other()s, in terms of sunlight being blocked or limbs snapped by the weight of another plants'.

I saw a small bit of this a long time ago, so I'm far from an expert. It seems very space-efficient, but there is definitely work involved. Lots of pruning and topping, and likely some rules for those that are applicable only in the practice of multi-tree plantings. But that's what youtube is for!  (This isn't me telling you "damn, go to youtube", just "I'd wager there's a host of mini-orchard owners with tutorial vids on the specifics of the practice").

---

Google is returning a lot on "Backyard Orchard Culture".  Seems like a good place to delve into it. From the skimming I did, they're treating this like it's a some kind of new innovation; but the instruction seems good enough.

Haven't even thought about this in 20 years. Growing up, one of my neighbors - retired sheriff, had a little shooting range on his property, good guy - kept a mini-orchard of 4 multi-tree plantings. When he was done harvesting, he'd let his horses in and they'd go crazy scarfing down what was left on the bushes (technically trees, but looked like big bushes). I got to see this once.  Those poor apples never stood a chance.

Hey - thanks for the memory recall!

Comment: Where do you get your knowledge from then?

Comment: In general, google, youtube, and a set of "The American Horticultural Society Illustrated Encyclopedia of Gardening" books I found at a rummage sale for $5. --- Youtube is an amazing learning resource. If there's a hobby, there's dozens of masters of that hobby posting how-to videos. --- From google, gardeningknowhow and SFGate are fair sites for brief overviews of a topic. If you scroll past the sites that optimize for search results, you can usually find several sites dedicated soley to what you're looking for. --- Horticultural society, Arbor Day Foundation, Wikipedia, etc

Comment: And the largest source of my horticultural knowledge: lots and lots of failure.

Comment: Also, though this isn't popular with some folks, cannabis grower sites are incredibly good resources. It's the nation's #1 cash crop by a huge margin, and its successful growers are really just forward-thinking farmers.. And there's fewer folks digging in their heels about what's "right and wrong" based on what they learned, because it's a culture of improvement rather than getting it right. (There's an adorable dearth of pest knowledge there, though, b/c cannabis is so hardy.) --- I haven't grown cannabis for almost 10 years, but the resource is there so I'm going to tap it.

Comment: Cannabis is illegal in most of the US, and is under federal law, so I can't look it up.

Comment: Nothing illegal about associated media. But the other resources are there if you don't want to use the pot farmers. I don't use them too often, but there's no one better for drainage analyses. They got me to try out coconut coir this year, and that stuff is amazing.